# Adding a scope to ruby gem validation of uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rubygems, monkeypatching, acts-as-taggable-on

[acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem has a built-in uniqueness validation:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, if: :validates_name_uniqueness?

def validates_name_uniqueness?
  true
end
```

How do I add a scope to this validation?

I want to add `scope: :user_id` and don't know how to edit a gem source code.

Comment: You might not want to monkey patch the gem, as this would affect how the method works in different areas of your code.

Comment: `validates_uniqueness_of` is a Rails method by the way, you can add a scope like this: `validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :user_id, if: :validates_name_uniqueness?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem with the help of acts_as_taggable_on.rb file in config/initializers:

```
module ActsAsTaggableOn
  class Tag < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    Tag.class_eval do
      _validators.reject!{ |key, _| key == :name }

      _validate_callbacks.each do |callback|
        callback.raw_filter.attributes.delete :name if callback.raw_filter.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator)
      end
      validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :user_id
    end
  end
end
```